# Can I use a variable in a script file path in Adobe Configurator 2.0?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm building an InDesign panel using Adobe Configurator 2.0. Basically, it provides a button which executes a javascript on click. I added the button by dragging a `Script File` in my panel and setting its `Script File` attribute to the desired path, e.g. `I:\someFolder\theScript.jsx`. This way, I can keep InDesign open and simply modify the script, save it, and press the button again to test it.

In the deployed version of the panel, however, I would like the button to point to a compiled version of the same script, e.g. `I:\someOTHERfolder\theScript.jsxbin`.

I could simply change the `Script File` attribute, but I have many of these buttons and it could become quite time consuming. I was kind of hoping I could use variables here, like so:

```
thePath = "I:\someFolder\"
theExtension = ".jsx"
```

Now the `Script File` attribute would become `thePath + "theScript" + theExtension` and I could change all the paths of all the buttons by simply changing these variables:

```
thePath = "I:\someOTHERfolder\"
theExtension = ".jsxbin"
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. Rather than using a `Script File`, I use a simple `Script`, which executes a command like this:

```
app.doScript(File(configurationObject.scriptFolder + "scriptName" + configurationObject.jsExtension), ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT);
```

The `configurationObject` is initialized *On Panel Initialization* with this code:

```
configurationObject =
{
  "jsExtension": ".jsx",
  "scriptFolder": "I:\\someFolder\\"
}
```